# Como tachar una fila entera de gridView en yii2

Tags: yii2

soy nuevo aprendiendo yii2 y tenia una duda.

Resulta que tengo un gridview que muestra datos de un model, el model tiene un atributo valido , si valido tiene valor 0 tengo que tachar todo el contenido de la fila que muestra los datos del modelo.
Estoy intentando hacerlo con la propiedad rowOptions de gridView y codifique lo siguiente:

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model) {
                                if ($model->valido == 0) {
                                    return '<s> tachar la fila entera  </s>';
                                }
                            }
```

Pero no funciona, no entiendo bien aun como es , el error que me salta es :

PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'data-key''

Les agradezco la ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La [documentación](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$rowOptions-detail) sobre `rowOptions` dice:

> ..This can be either an array specifying the common HTML attributes for
>   all body rows, or an anonymous function that returns an array of the
>   HTML attributes..

`rowOptions` no sirve para modificar el contenido de una fila. Debes devolver un `array asociativo` con los **atributos html** que quieras setear. Igualmente
puedes lograr el tachado usando `rowOptions` y `CSS` de la siguiente manera:

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model) {
    if ($model->valido == 0) {
        return ['class' => 'tachado'];
    }
 }
```

Esto agregara una clase `tachado` a la fila. Con el siguiente `CSS` podrás lograr el efecto que estás buscando:

```
.tachado {
    text-decoration: line-through
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo